# ¿Como mostrar una matriz con filas y columnas?

Tags: python

Mi código en python:

```
Matriz = []
cont = 32
for fila in range(4):
    Matriz.append([])
    for columna in range(8):
        Matriz[fila].append(columna)
        Matriz[fila][columna] = cont
        cont = cont - 1
print(Matriz)
input()
```

Lo que obtengo (digitos distintos, pero misma idea):

```
[[1,2,3] [1,2,3] [1,2,3] [1,2,3]]
```

Lo que quiero obtener es (pero con mi código), aun que sin utilizar numpy.

```
1 2 3
1 2 3
1 2 3
```

Muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿Qué te impide llegar al resultado deseado? ¿Dónde topas?

Comment: Puedes hacerlo con un solo for, pero... cual es tu error o problema?

Comment: Simplemente no lo se hacer :(

Comment: pero tu codigo te funciona o no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno modificando un poco tu codigo tengo lo siguiente:

```
Matriz = []
```

en esta matriz voy a almacenar los valores que se obtendrán en cada columna atreves de  otra matriz auxiliar.

```
#almacenar valores a mi matriz
for fila in range(3):
    matrizAux = []
    for columna in range(1,4):
        matrizAux.append(columna)
    Matriz.append(matrizAux)
```

En este codigo se va a encargar de recorrer fila (3) y columnas (3) ,
adentro del primero for voy a declarar una matriz_auxiliar donde obtendre los valores de cada columna en cada iteracion, para despues agregarlos a mi Matriz global.
Una vez que tengo ingresado los datos, los muestro:

```
#recorrer la matriz
for fila in range(3):
    for columna in range(3):
        print(Matriz[fila][columna],end=" ")
    print()
```

Recorremos filas (3) y columnas (3) para después mostrarlo con mi variable Matriz global en cada iteración especificada.
Como resultado quedaría :

```
1 2 3 
1 2 3 
1 2 3
```

Comment: te puedes ahorrar un `for`